# use Parallel.ForEach with function in list

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I would like to do this with  Parallel.ForEach. how can I do?

```
partial class Form1: Form
{
private List<my_class> lstmy_class = new List<my_class>();  

private void execute_tpl(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = tokenSource.Token;
        var tab_task = new Task[lstmy_class.Count];
        try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lstmy_class.Count; i++)
                {
                   tab_task[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => lstmy_class[i].Calcul(token));
                }

                Task.WaitAll(tab_task);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : "+ex.GetType());
            }
    }
}

class my_class{ 
... 
    public void Calcul(CancellationToken token)
    {
       // do work       
    }   
}
```

I try with :

```
Parallel.ForEach<my_class>(lstChartClass, () => Calcul(token));
```

but the compiler don't want this syntax. I don't find the good syntax.

I try also with `Parallel.ForEach<my_class>(lstChartClass, (i) => lstChartClass[i]Calcul());` but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `Parallel.ForEach` is an `Action<TSource>`, meaning that it must be a delegate that returns nothing but takes a `TSource` as a parameter.  Therefore, the syntax for your case would be

```
Parallel.ForEach(lstmy_class, n => n.Calcul(token));
```

Comment: @Florent You're welcome!  If this solved your problem, you can [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).